# How to scroll in Monodevelop 3.0 Android UI Designer?

Tags: monodevelop

When I use a scrollview in one of the screens, and the content is taller than the viewport, how do I scroll down to see the rest of the content?

Clicking and dragging will move the items around in stead of scrolling to the rest of the content. Scrollwheel or scrollbar only move the designer, not the design itself.

I can't find anything in the [Monodevelop documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Designer_Overview) about this, and due to the young age of 3.0, Google doesn't know anything about this either.

**Edit 29-05-2012:**
I've updated to the [newest version (3.0.2)](http://monodevelop.com/Download/Release_Notes/Release_Notes_for_MonoDevelop_3.0.2) but there are no changes to the absence of scrolling in the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

The designer doesn't yet support scrolling the contents. Support for scrolling will be included in future releases.